# Когда я пишу python в cmd открывается Microsoft store

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не знаю почему. По идее должна запуститься IDE с тремя >>>, но этого не происходит. Как исправить?

Comment: Тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-window-store-when-i-type-python хорошо описано решение данной проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого заходишь в настройки, выбираешь пункт "Apps" (приложения), потом App extension aliases это настройки Python,и отключаешь расширения app installer. Всё, теперь должно работать :) 
А для наглядного примера оставлю ссылку на видос на английском
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXeAYfrfwkM